# Retrieve variable value - non input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP File with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var page = '1';
</script>

<select class='search' name="type" ID="type">
    <option value='%'>All Types</option>
    .....
</select>
```

I know how to retrieve the value of the type with JQuery.

Is there a way (besides a hidden field) to retrieve the value of the JavaScript variable `page`?
I have tried this but keep getting undefined:

```
 var page = $("#" + this.page).val();
```

Comment: `page` should be available to you anywhere on that page. All you should need to do is `alert(page);` - it's not an element, just a variable.

Comment: "to retrieve variable the javascript variable page" ?? Does that make sense? I don't see any html elements with `id="1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `page` is global throughout the scope of your document. You can access simply by

```
var myPage = page;
```

as long as it was set in the document before this script was ran.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply:

```
var page = $("#" + page).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation, not knowing the real purpose, would be using data attributes.

So your html would include `<body data-page="1">` (you can add it to any element).

And your JS would do `var page =  $('body').data('page'); //page = 1`

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

http://api.jquery.com/data/